# How to exclude links using POST parameters with wget

Tags: url, post, wget

I want to download all accessible html files under www.site.com/en/. However, there are a lot of linked URLS with post parameters on the site (e.g. pages 1,2,3.. for each product category). I want wget NOT to download these links. I'm using

```
-R "*\?*"
```

But it's not perfect because it only removes the file after downloading it.

Is there some way for example to filter the links followed by wget with a regex?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to avoid those files with a regex, you would have to use `--reject-regex '(.*)\?(.*)'` but it will work only with wget version 1.15, so I would recommend you to check your wget version first.