# How do you filter wget follow links using --reject-regex?

Tags: regex, wget

I am trying to mirror a site for local archival using `wget`. Everything is working well (auth headers etc), except the site was written such that calling the GET method on a certain URL deletes resources, e.g. accessing

`http://site.domain.com/users/Delete/{uid}`

deletes the user with id=uid. I would like `wget` to follow all links on the site expect the ones that contain the pattern `"/Delete/"`.

According to the [GNU wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options) you can filter URLs using `wget --reject-regex`. I'm using `wget` version 1.15 which was not compiled with libpcre support so I have tried to use standard [POSIX ERE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) like this (amongst other attempts) :

`wget --reject-regex='.*Delete.*' -P /path_to_mirror_dir/ -k -p -m -E -c -rH -Dsite.domain.com https://site.domain.com/Home/` ([see explainshell](https://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=wget%20--reject-regex=%27.*Delete.*%27%20-P%20/path_to_mirror_dir/%20-k%20-p%20-m%20-E%20-c%20-rH%20-Dsite.domain.com%20https://site.domain.com/Home/))

as per answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/156045/how-to-download-with-wget-without-following-links-with-parameters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820412/how-to-exclude-links-using-post-parameters-with-wget). However, the URLs are still being followed and so the resources deleted.

Is it possible to filter followed URLs using `reject-regex`?

P.S. I briefly looked at [httrack](https://web.archive.org/web/20200216184216/http://manpages.ubuntu.com:80/manpages/precise/man1/httrack.1.html), but didn't investigate further when I couldn't see how to send the HTTP headers explicitly. Also, I would like to understand this `wget` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget --exclude-directories='*/Delete' -P /path_to_mirror_dir/ -k -p -m -E -c -rH -Dsite.domain.com https://site.domain.com/Home/
```

([Explainshell](http://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%20%20%20%20wget%20--exclude-directories%3D%27*%2FDelete%27%20-P%20%2Fpath_to_mirror_dir%2F%20-k%20-p%20-m%20-E%20-c%20-rH%20-Dsite.domain.com%20https%3A%2F%2Fsite.domain.com%2FHome%2F))

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, but I did try that and it still follows the link. The `--exclude-directories` option refers to directories on the server side ([example](http://serverfault.com/questions/324555/how-to-exclude-certain-directories-while-using-wget)), which I know nothing about.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The problem was the [recursive accept/reject options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html) only work with `--recursive (-r)` (as expected), but the `--mirror (-m)` option supersedes it, so the `--reject-regex` pattern was ignored. Thus, the command that works is

`wget --reject-regex='.*Delete.*' -P /path_to_mirror_dir/ -k -p -E -c -rH -Dsite.domain.com https://site.domain.com/Home/`